Sitecore 10 ExperienceForms on Form Submit not inserting data into Database
I have built a Sitecore 10.1 form with multi page level which includes upload file and google captcha.
On submit Button I have attached the following action (Save Data, Send Email with Attachment, Validate Google Captcha) when I am trying to submit the forms it's getting submitted without any error, and Not seeing any obvious JS errors in the console as well.
I tried the below two scenarios.

I submitted the form with an Attachment, it gets submitted without email being triggered and no data inserted into the table [sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData] but can see the attached file name in the table [sitecore_forms_filestorage].[FileStorage].

I submitted the form without any Attachment, it gets submitted without email being triggered and no data inserted into the table [sitecore_forms_storage].[FieldData] and show the below attached stack trace.


In both scenarios, mail is not triggered and data not inserted in the [FieldData] table
System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
       at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.BaseFormBuilderController.ProcessFormData(FormDataModel data)
       at Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Controllers.FormBuilderController.Index(FormDataModel data)
       at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
       at System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c.b__9_0(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.b__11_0()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<>c__DisplayClass11_1.b__2()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_6.b__3()
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass3_1.b__5(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c.b__152_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c.b__20_1(IAsyncResult asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState)
       at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStepImpl(IExecutionStep step)
       at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Any idea on this issues?
I tried the below additional ways to figure out the issues

Create a new custom save action to save the data in a different table by extending the submitActionData, with additional logs for Info and Error.
On click of submit the form is submitting but its not saving the data in the custom table as well the Info log is not found.


Can you check the value that is in the label value of Submit button?

The label is 'Submit' only

Can you check logs once, it will help to rule out any form submit action triggering or not so that we can drill down either it's breaking or submit action not firing.

I checked logs and could not find any error. This issue is happening only in the CM environment.
